# SQL Server Reporting Service render to pdf character encoding issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, fonts

My problem is rather hard to explain. I have a SSRS 2008 R2 Generating pdf files in Persian language. Generated pdfs are completely readable and correct in view. But, I can not search text in them. I have tracked problem and saw that embedded fonts in pdf are using special characters that are not available in normal font for example one of the characters is U+10017e witch is not a normal character.

To me it seems that SSRS has ignored characters that where already available and created a font with special characters and then converted my text to that characters.

I have created pdfs with same fonts using other tools and no problem.
I have tried to change the encoding of the pdf files but the problem is not in the encoding characters are changed altogether.

I have no idea where to look. Any hint will be appreciated.

--Edit--

[Sample of pdf file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=59118483007719910579)

Answer (score 1):

This PDF files comes with the broken CMAP (the internal map that maps visual glyphs to their Unicode values). Microsoft aknowledges this issue with some locales in their [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2924996)
One of the solution they suggest is to make sure the server's locale is set to English. So maybe you should try to change the locale to/from English to see how it affects the PDF export.

Comment: It seems promising. Let me check and see what happens.

Comment: that's interesting but definetely the issue in the reporting engine. I would try to use another Unicode font to see if another font works better, the font should meet these requirements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159713(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: I don't see any suggestions about the font. But as I have tried many fonts who all have correct unicode mappings I don't think the issue is with the font.